# why does "page isn't working" show when I try to login or do something in my website?

Tags: server, webserver, web-hosting

I uploaded my folder on the server I purchased using WinSCP. When I view my site, it shows my index and all I can do is view those pages in my navbar, but when I try to login or send a registration form, :

[image: this is exactly what it shows]

I do not know what just happened. I also tried uploading before but I never encountered this problem. Any help? What should I do?

Comment: What operating system? What did you upload?

Comment: The laptop's OS that I used uploading is Windows 7 Ultimate. I uploaded my folder where the site I created from localhost. @gunwin

Comment: I mean, the OS of your server. And what type of file did you upload? HTML, PHP, ASPX something else? This 500 error is likely a result of malformed code. You need to enable useful error messages, but that depends on the OS, the language etc

Comment: I'm not really sure what OS are you referring to, sorry. But I used WinSCP when I uploaded my folder. My files are PHP. @gunwin

Comment: Add the following two lines to the top of your PHP code: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` this should show you a useful error message.

Comment: on top of every php file that i have? @gunwin

Comment: on top of the file you are trying to navigate to. So if you are visiting index.php then put it at the top of that file. There is probably an error in your code somewhere and this should indicate where that is.

Comment: okay, will do that thank you sir @gunwin

Comment: did what u said and now i got this error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_verify() in login.php` @gunwin

Comment: but this is working on localhost @gunwin

Comment: i checked my php using` phpinfo()` and it says that it's 5.5.30 @gunwin